# dirPagination : nested ng-repeats

Tags: angularjs, dirpagination

I need to make use of the `ng-repeats` in the **dirPagination**(angular plugin), I have also created the plunker.
I need the current object to have `ng-repeat` at two different places

- 1 rating images
- 2 services offered

[Link for plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/8ByRaRbvZJMEnW4FakoO?p=preview)

If you refer to the plnkr, there is a ratingImages attribute in each object, what i want is that i need to make use of `ng-repeat` in side the `dir-paginate` for example html :

`<div class="rating">
    <img ng-repeat="ratingImage in provider.ratingImages" src="{{ratingImage }}" alt="" />
     <span>(5 reviews)</span>
 </div>`

But by doing this i receive an error `ng-repeat:dupes`

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/8ByRaRbvZJMEnW4FakoO?p=preview

Comment: Please, clarify your question.

Comment: I have updated the question please have a look, if still not able to understand will provide more description.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it

```
<div class="rating">
     <!-- ng-repeat = ratingImage in provider.ratingImages -->
 <img  ng-repeat="ratingImage in provider.ratingImages track by $index" src="{{ratingImage}}" alt="" />
  <span>(5 reviews)</span>
</div>
```

note i use track by $index for dupes
[read more about it here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes)